# Im trying to find the max and min value and its respective index. However I cant get the indexmin

Tags: arrays, c

Find the minimum element of the array and its corresponding index.
I can't get the the minimum index to work. Do I add else statement under each if statement?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int array[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} , i;
    **//finding max and min, and its respective index**
    int max = array[0] , min = array[0];
    int indmin , indmax;

    for( i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
    {
        if(array[i] > max) 
        {
            max = array[i];
            indmax = i;

        }
        if(array[i] < min)
        {
            min = array[i];
            indmin = i;
        }


        }

//print the max and min value and its indexs
    printf("\nMaximum element is %d\t index is %d", max , indmax);
    printf("\nMinimum element is %d\t index is %d", min , indmin);

}
```

Comment: You should initialise both `indmin` and `indmax` to zero before starting the loop, since you've also set the `min` and `max` to the first entry.

Comment: You do remember that uninitialized local variables really *are* uninitialized? That they will have an *indeterminate* value (that you should look at like garbage)? With that in mind, please explain to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) what happens if `array[0]` is the lowest (or highest) value in the array? When will `indmin` (or `indmax`) then be set?

Answer (score 2):

Initialize `indmin` and `indmax`.  When defining the array leave out the size so it's derived from the data.  When iterating over the array use `sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array)` to let compiler determine the size of the array instead of hard-coding it.  Minimize scope of variable `i`.  Use a function to print output for less duplication:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(const char *prompt, int value, int index) {
    printf("%s element is %d\t index is %d\n", prompt, value, index);
}

int main() {
    int array[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    int min = array[0];
    int indmin = 0;
    int max = array[0];
    int indmax = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array); i++) {
        if(array[i] > max) {
            max = array[i];
            indmax = i;
        }
        if(array[i] < min) {
            min = array[i];
            indmin = i;
        }
    }
    print("Maximum", max, indmax);
    print("Minimum", min, indmin);
}
```

You could refactor this by creating a struct to keep the value and index together:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct value_index {
    int value;
    int index;
};

void print(const char *prompt, struct value_index *vi) {
    printf("%s element is %d\t index is %d\n", prompt, vi->value, vi->index);
}

int main() {
    int array[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    struct value_index min = { array[0], 0 };
    struct value_index max = { array[0], 0 };
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array); i++) {
        if(array[i] > max.value) {
            max.value = array[i];
            max.index = i;
        }
        if(array[i] < min.value) {
            min.value = array[i];
            min.index = i;
        }
    }
    print("Maximum", &max);
    print("Minimum", &min);
}
```

Or you could realize that you only need the original array along with the two indices.  To make my version even better than @Fe2O3's answer, I used a macro to make mine smaller (and if bait works then I will claim mine is easier to read) :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(const char *prompt, int *arr, int index) {
    printf("%s element is %d\t index is %d\n", prompt, arr[index], index);
}

int main() {
    int array[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    int indmin = 0;
    int indmax = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array); i++) {
#define CMP_AND_SET(OP, V) if(array[i] OP array[V]) V = i
        CMP_AND_SET(<, indmin);
        CMP_AND_SET(>, indmax);
#unset CMP_AND_SET
    }
    print("Maximum", array, indmax);
    print("Minimum", array, indmin);
}
```

Building on @Fe2O3's branchless idea combined with an initialized array which I find to compact and quite readable:

```
indmin = (int[]) { indmin, i }[array[i] < array[indmin]];      
indmax = (int[]) { indmax, i }[array[i] > array[indmax]];
```

By using `(a < b) <=> -1 * (-a > -b)` you can write the last one as (note: UB if array contains INT_MIN):

```
indmax = (int[]) { indmax, i }[-array[i] < -array[indmax]];
```

I would use a local macro to reduce code duplication by using macro to generate either the first version by passing in the operator (see above) or the 2nd version by passing in a factor `F`:

```
#define MINMAX(V, F) V = (int[]) { V, i }[F * array[i] < F * array[V]]
indmin = MINMAX(indmin, 1);
indmax = MINMAX(indmax, -1);
```

I am totally cheating but you can shuffle the min and max elements to fixed positions within the source array.  No storage overhead.  This would be the opposite of branchless.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(const char *prompt, int value) {
    printf("%8s = %3d\n", prompt, value);
}

int swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 42, 5, -42, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    const int min = 0;
    const int max = sizeof arr/sizeof *arr - 1;
    for(int i = 1; i < max + 1; i++ )
        arr[i] < arr[min] && swap(arr + i, arr + min) ||
        arr[i] > arr[max] && swap(arr + i, arr + max);
    print("min", arr[min]);
    print("max", arr[max]);
}
```

Comment: "Easier to read?!?!" Those UPPERCASE macros give me goosebumps, looking for all the world like COBOL is climbing out of the grave for Halloween... `:-)`

Comment: wrt "latest volley": Might wanna remove the printing of what are presumed to be the original index values of the min/max values... Pushing those to the extremities kinda changes things... :-) (I'm not sure rearranging the original array is allowed...)

Comment: Someone mentioned creativity :-)

Comment: It will be fun if op checks in.

Comment: Yes, the audience reaction will be interesting! `:-)` I added `puts( "Swap");` inside `swap()`, fed a scrambled version of the array to the algorithm and saw "Swap Swap Swap Swap"... High points for creativity. Judges are still calculating points for "efficiency".... `:-)`

Comment: And, what I hope is a final salvo back in your direction... `:-)` (Gotta find another hobby... `:)`)

Answer (score 1):

Leaving variables uninitialised is asking **Demon of Hard-To-Find Bugs** to co-author your code. Define variables close to where they are used to increase clarity. And, don't define more variables than you need. (Common beginner mistake to make another copy "just in case"...)

```
// use the spacebar to increase readability
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // let the compiler assign the size of an initialised array
    int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    // use fewer variables
    int indmin = 0, indmax = 0;

    // don't compare an element (arr[0]) to itself
    for( int i = 1 ; i < sizeof array/sizeof array[0]; i++ )
        if( array[ i ] > array[ indmax ] )
            indmax = i; // updated

        else
        if( array[ i ] < array[ indmin ] )
            indmin = i; // updated
        // don't add unnecessary braces (imho)
        // this isn't the 17th century in need of needless filligree.

    // use '\n' at the END of output. sometimes needed to 'flush' output buffer
    printf("Maximum element is %d\t index is %d\n", array[ indmax ] , indmax);
    printf("Minimum element is %d\t index is %d\n", array[ indmin ] , indmin);

    return 0;
}
```

```
Maximum element is 10    index is 9
Minimum element is 1     index is 0
```

**EDIT:**
So, there's a *friendly* competition going on in this question... :-)
How's this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // let the compiler assign the size of an initialised array
    // use shorter names to expose operations (not lengthy variable names)
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int iMin = 0, iMax = 0;

    // don't compare an element to itself
    for( int i = 1; i < sizeof arr/sizeof arr[0]; i++ ) {
        // use "branchless" coding for speed.
        int n = arr[i] > arr[iMax];
        iMax = n*i + !n*iMax;
        n = arr[i] < arr[iMin];
        iMin = n*i + !n*iMin;
    }

    // reduce duplication of static data
    char *fmt = "%s element is %d\t index is %d\n";
    printf( fmt, "Maximum", arr[ iMax ], iMax );
    printf( fmt, "Minimum", arr[ iMin ], iMin );

    return 0;
}
```

Same output. 
Ball's in your court @Allan `:-)`

---

**EDIT:**
There has been an advance on the last offering that needs to be addressed...

Here we go whole-hog, splurging-out with a third 'container' (mm[0]) to catch all those indexes that satisfy neither conditional ('<' & '>'). AND, a 4th 'container' (mm[3]) that doesn't change from being initialised to 0, the index of the 1st element. Besides being *cryptic* (not advised), this may-or-may-not be more expensive with its multiple array offset calculations... But, it's fun to look at...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // added two elements to show 0 and nElem are not 'flukes'
    // this really does find and report the min/max values
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 42, 5, -42, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int i, mm[1 + 2 + 1] = { 0 };

    // assign 'i' to mm[ 0 or 1 or 2 ]. 0=latest, 1=max, 2=min, (3 unaffected)
    for( i = 1; i < sizeof arr/sizeof arr[0]; i++ )
        mm[ (arr[i] > arr[mm[1]]) + 2*(arr[i] < arr[mm[2]]) ] = i;

    mm[ 0 ] = i-1; // always pick up the last index. Thanks @A Wind!

    // now... this is getting silly!!
    char *fmt = "%5s = %3d @ arr[%d]\n";
    char *type[] = { "last", "max", "min", "first" };
    i = 3; do printf( fmt, type[i], arr[ mm[i] ], mm[i] ); while( --i >= 0 );

    return 0;
}
```

```
first =   1 @ arr[0]
  min = -42 @ arr[6]
  max =  42 @ arr[4]
 last =  10 @ arr[11]
```

Y'know... This might be interesting to try to apply to 3-way branching as is needed for binary searching; determining '<', '=' or '>'... Hmmm...

---

**EDIT:** (another variation on a theme at the suggestion of a worthy competitor :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    struct {
        char *label;
        int ind;
    } mm[] = {
        { "last" },
        { "maximum" },
        { "minimum" },
        { "first" },
    };

    int i, arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 42, 5, -42, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    for( i = 1; i < sizeof arr/sizeof arr[0]; i++ )
        mm[ (arr[i] > arr[mm[1].ind]) + 2*(arr[i] < arr[mm[2].ind]) ].ind = i;
    mm[ 0 ].ind = --i; // always pick up the last index. Thanks @A Wind!

    for( i = sizeof mm/sizeof mm[0]; --i >= 0; /* space for rent */ )
        printf( "%8s = %3d @ arr[%d]\n", mm[i].label, arr[ mm[i].ind ], mm[i].ind );

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Trying to cover ALL the bases, here are three more ways *to skin a cat*

```
/* Minimalist */
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int mm[3] = { 0 },
        arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 42, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        i = sizeof arr/sizeof arr[0];

    while( --i )
        mm[ 2*(arr[i] > arr[mm[2]]) + (arr[i] < arr[mm[1]]) ] = i;

    char *fmt = "arr[%d] = %3d M%simum\n";
    printf( fmt, mm[1], arr[mm[1]], "in" );
    printf( fmt, mm[2], arr[mm[2]], "ax" );

    return 0;
}
```

```
/* Recursive - for brevity, excluding the index; just reporting two values */
#include <stdio.h>

int amin( int a[], int i ) { // NB: "amin", not "main"
    int j = --i ? amin( a, i ) : i;
    return (a[j]<a[i])*j + (a[j] > a[i])*i;
}

int amax( int a[], int i ) {
    int j = --i ? amax( a, i ) : i;
    return (a[j]>a[i])*j + (a[j]<a[i])*i;
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, },
        sz = sizeof arr/sizeof arr[0];

    char *fmt = "M%simum: %3d\n";
    printf( fmt, "in", arr[ amin(arr, sz) ] );
    printf( fmt, "ax", arr[ amax(arr, sz) ] );

    return 0;
}
```

```
/* And, simply brute force using a library function */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmp( const void *a, const void *b ) { return *(int*)a - *(int*)b; }

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        sz = sizeof arr/sizeof arr[0];

    qsort( arr, sz, sizeof arr[0], cmp );

    char *fmt = "M%simum: %3d\n";
    printf( fmt, "in", arr[   0  ] );
    printf( fmt, "ax", arr[ --sz ] ); // again, thanks to @A Wind

    return 0;
}
```

*Many* ways to skin a cat.